# Uso de la coma antes y después de "y que"

Tags: ortografía, puntuación, queísmo-dequeísmo

¿Qué significado tiene la coma antes y después de la expresión "y que" en este texto?

> Los nacidos fuera de España de padre o madre, abuelo o abuela, que originariamente hubieran sido españoles, y que, como consecuencia de haber sufrido exilio por razones políticas, ideológicas o de creencia o de orientación e identidad sexual, hubieran perdido o renunciado a la nacionalidad española, podrán optar a la nacionalidad española, a los efectos del artículo 20 del Código Civil”.

Comment: Básicamente, la de marcar una pausa entre dos oraciones extensas.

Comment: ¿Y si se elimina la coma antes de "y que" en qué cambia el sentido del texto?

Comment: No cambia, simplemente permite al lector tomar una pausa más larga. Si la frase anterior es corta, la primera coma se suele omitir.

Answer (score 3):

A veces las comas se utilizan como inflexiones no solo para separar partes dentro de la oración sino también para encerrar una frase, tal como lo hacen los paréntesis.

En el caso de la pregunta, la frase original sería:

> ...  que originariamente hubieran sido españoles, y que hubieran perdido o renunciado a la nacionalidad española,...

Pero se añade la condicionalidad o circunstancia encerrada entres dos comas:

> ... que originariamente hubieran sido españoles, y que, `como consecuencia de haber sufrido exilio por razones políticas, ideológicas o de creencia o de orientación e identidad sexual`, hubieran perdido o renunciado a la nacionalidad española,

---

Por apuntar un ejemplo menos complicado:

> Mi gato, al que le gusta mucho comer, solo prefiere atún y salmón.

Donde la frase declaratoria sin la condición o circunstancia es:

> Mi gato solo prefiere atún y salmón.

Comment: ¿Y si se elimina la coma antes de "y que" en qué cambia el sentido del texto?

Answer (score 0):

En la oración:

"Los nacidos fuera de España de padre o madre, abuelo o abuela, que originariamente hubieran sido españoles, y que, como consecuencia de haber sufrido exilio por razones políticas, ideológicas o de creencia o de orientación e identidad sexual, hubieran perdido o renunciado a la nacionalidad española, podrán optar a la nacionalidad española ..."

las comas que encierran el inciso "como consecuencia de haber sufrido ... identidad sexual" son opcionales. Se podría haber dicho perfectamente:

"Los nacidos fuera de España de padre o madre, abuelo o abuela, que originariamente hubieran sido españoles, y que como consecuencia de haber sufrido exilio por razones políticas, ideológicas o de creencia o de orientación e identidad sexual hubieran perdido o renunciado a la nacionalidad española, podrán optar a la nacionalidad española ..."

Las comas serían más necesarias si no hubiera coma antes de "y que":

"Los nacidos fuera de España de padre o madre, abuelo o abuela, que originariamente hubieran sido españoles y que, como consecuencia de haber sufrido exilio por razones políticas, ideológicas o de creencia o de orientación e identidad sexual, hubieran perdido o renunciado a la nacionalidad española, podrán optar a la nacionalidad española ..."

Mi entendimiento es que el escritor las usó para acotar un inciso bastante extenso.

Más allá de la pregunta, debo decir que la oración está mal redactada por puntuación y ambigüedad:

(1) Los nacidos fuera de España de padre o madre, abuelo o abuela, que originariamente hubieran sido españoles ("nacidos de padre o madre", está bien, no así "(nacidos de) abuelo o abuela"). También es inconsistente esa coma entre "padre o madre" y "abuelo o abuela".

(2) El antecedente de "que originariamente hubieran sido españoles..." y de "que hubieran perdido o renunciado a la nacionalidad española" es ambiguo: pueden ser tanto los hijos/nietos como los padres/abuelos.

Nota: En mi dialecto, no usamos "optar a". Solo decimos "optar por". (https://www.rae.es/dpd/optar)

Comment: ¿Y si se elimina la coma antes de "y que" en qué cambia el sentido de la oración?

Comment: Si se elimina la coma, la "y" tiene un valor puramente aditivo. En cambio, detrás de la coma la "y" adquiere valor más expresivo, tal vez adversativo (que nacieron en España pero perdieron la nacionalidad española). En la Ortografía de la RAE, encontramos este ejemplo similar: "Le aconsejé que no comprara esa casa, y no hizo caso."

Comment: O sea que ese texto tal y como está redactado significa que podrán optar a la nacionalidad española todas las personas cuyo padre o abuelo hubiera sido originariamente español, incluyendo aquellos que perdieron la nacionalidad española pero solo por causa del exilio. La pérdida de la nacionalidad española por exilio no es condicional para que la persona de padre o abuelo originariamente español pueda optar a la nacionalidad española. ¿Es así o no?

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo con tu punto 3. En mi opinión, *optar a* y *optar por* tienen significados diferentes. La segunda expresión indica elección sin más, mientras que la primera indica iniciar un proceso que puede llevar a algo. Por ejemplo, quienes se presentan a una oposición optan a un número de plazas, pero no optan por ellas.

Comment: @Gorpik Perdón por el fallido, pero en mi dialecto solo existe "optar por".

Answer (score 0):

Los textos jurídicos son, como otros lenguajes corporativos, bastantes sui-generis, por ello habitualmente no se adaptan en su redacción a las habituales fórmulas que rigen para el resto del lenguaje y así gustan de ser retóricos o abusar de ciertas figuras en su redacción, por último será labor del juez interpretar aquello que quiso decir el legislador.

Dicho esto, en la expresión "y que" que va entre comas, "...*hubieran sido españoles, y que, como consecuencia*...", tenemos que distinguir dos aspectos.

Primero el sentido y utilización de la coma dentro de la frase, y segundo, la utilización de la partícula "que", en este caso como relativo.

---

La Rae, cuando habla del uso de la coma, en el caso que nos ocupa, dice;

> 1. Usos lingüísticos
>
> 1.1. Para delimitar incisos. Deben utilizarse dos comas, una delante del comienzo del inciso y otra al final. En este caso, la coma sí
> indica pausa y el inciso se lee en un tono más grave que el del resto
> del enunciado...

Por tanto, las comas están delimitando un inciso que ha hecho el legislador, y que en este caso, se esta refiriendo a algo o a alguien.

De esta manera dentro del entrecomillado ",*y que*," hallamos una "y" como conjunción aditiva y un "que", como pronombre relativo, ambas partículas podríamos sustituirlas por "los cuales", para referirnos en su conjunto a "*Los nacidos fuera de España de padre o madre, abuelo o abuela, que originariamente hubieran sido españoles*"

> Los nacidos fuera de España de padre o madre, abuelo o abuela, que
> originariamente hubieran sido españoles, **los cuales**, como consecuencia
> de haber sufrido exilio por razones políticas, ideológicas o de
> creencia o de orientación e identidad sexual...

---

El significado que tiene la coma delante y detrás, en esta frase, es la de hacer un inciso para referirse a "*los nacidos fuera de España de padre o madre, abuelo o abuela, que originariamente hubieran sido españoles*", como si realmente el texto comenzará a partir de ahí. Pruebe igualmente a eliminar el ",y que," y sustitúyalo por " y que", sin las comas, el pronombre relativo se convertirá en una locución conjuntiva "que", la cual introduce una oración subordinada y ya no necesitará referirse a los beneficiarios que aparecen al principio del texto.

> Los nacidos fuera de España de padre o madre, abuelo o abuela, que
> originariamente hubieran sido españoles **y que** como consecuencia de haber
> sufrido exilio por razones políticas, ideológicas o de creencia o de
> orientación e identidad sexual...

---

Nota: El texto hace referencia a la nueva "Ley de Memoria Democrática", conocida en Iberoamérica como "Ley de los Bisnietos". Para información y aclaración en un sentido jurídico https://www.legaltoday.com/opinion/articulos-de-opinion/es-la-ley-de-memoria-democratica-una-autentica-ley-de-bisnietos-2022-07-29/

Comment: Según explica el Centro de Descendientes de Españoles Unidos (CEDEU) la coma antes de "y que" significa que la pérdida de la nacionalidad española debido al exilio no es una condición obligatoria para que la persona de padre o abuelo originariamente español pueda optar a la nacionalidad española. La pérdida de la nacionalidad española solo se justifica si fue debido al exilio para que la persona de padre o abuelo español pueda optar a la nacionalidad española. ¿Es así o no?

Comment: Así es, esta usted en lo cierto, sin embargo, como curiosidad "...se venía diciendo que esta nueva ley posibilitaría que cualquier bisnieto de español podía tener derecho a adquirir la nacionalidad, cuando solo es posible para aquellos bisnietos y bisnietas descendientes de personas que debieron abandonar España exiliados por razones políticas, ideológicas o de creencia o de orientación e identidad sexual".